# Creating multiple text fields in javafx

Tags: javafx

Is there anyway I can do a for loop to create multiple textfields. Say I want like 20 text fields...do I have to create them individually?

Comment: Yes... just write a `for` loop and create the text fields inside it. It's not really clear what the question is.

Comment: How do I name it like tetxfield1 textfield2 etc...

Comment: If you need to refer to them outside the loop, put them in an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really clear what your question is. Just write a for loop and create each `TextField` inside it.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TwentyTextFields extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        final int numTextFields = 20 ;
        TextField[] textFields = new TextField[numTextFields];
        VBox root = new VBox(5);
        for (int i = 1; i <= numTextFields; i++) {
            TextField tf = new TextField();
            String name = "Text field "+i ;
            tf.setOnAction(e -> {
                System.out.println("Action on "+name+": text is "+tf.getText());
            });
            root.getChildren().add(tf);
            textFields[i-1] = tf ;
        }
        Scene scene = new Scene(new ScrollPane(root), 250, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```